# Why is there package info from a 3rd party nuget package persisiting for all projects now?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

This is happening in both Visual Studio 2019 and 2022. The 3rd party package I was using in one of my projects is called [FastCrud](https://github.com/MoonStorm/FastCrud) which is an extension of the popular Dapper ORM. Somehow, some way now whenever I create a new project from scratch it will pre-populate all the 'Package' information with that of the FastCRUD package. So for example, I just created a new blank project I named Test Project, and when I go into the project properties this is what I see:

[image]

Even worse it seems to now add this to existing projects when I open them in VS! Why is it doing this and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you have accidentally updated the default project template?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement I checked, I don't see any references to that in the templates files/folders for VS2019 or 2022. Is there some other settings in VS itself that might account for this? You're certainly right that it seems like some global setting has been altered